# spring boot integration test for non spring service from scratch

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I am new to Spring with some experience in Java/Junit. I want to do integration testing for some web services.

Right now I am doing manual testing using Postman. The requirement is that I have to post some complex Json's to some internal service like below.

This is the end point. In future I might have to test it on different environments and I can use spring profile.

POST /rsg/rest/1.0.0/xxxxxx HTTP/1.1

However, I am confused how to get started. This might not be a spring service as I am not having access to the code.

I have been reading a lot about testing JSON with libraries like Gson, Rest Assured, Test Rest Template etc. I am not sure which way would be the best.

To get started I have created POJO's for my JSON and used Gson to create a JSON Object.

Now which spring feature I can use to post it to my URL and get response. I saw some tutorials for spring-boot-starter-test and some other stuff but most of the times they are creating some application or controllers or mock mvc etc.

I am not sure if I need all this to get started. Can someone please guide me in getting started, how I can test the above thing with spring boot in a nice way.

What could be the starting point or simple steps to test this.

Also in JSON I might have to replace lot of values at run time for which I think some feature of spring might be useful

Thanks,
Vicky

Comment: Please try to solve it yourself, write some code. Then add the code part where you're stuck along with the expected behaviour and the error message. You can't expect us to write code for you.

Comment: As a starter I would recommend to create a separate test project that will test your running application. You can use a unit test libs to achieve this but it's up to. You test project will call your application just like your "POST /rsg/rest/1.0.0/xxxxxx HTTP/1.1" and you can achieve this some http client like Apache or some other.  Hope this helps as a starter.

Comment: @msparer I have some code and am playing with it. What I meant was is there some nice tutorial or guide to get  started with testing JSON POST along with Spring. I found many links but couldn't find a good one just for this purpose.

I wanted to know whether I need to create things like controllers, application, mock mvc to start testing something like this in terms of spring. I tested it with simple post using REst Assured and I am able to post, but wanted to use spring features and learn testing in context of spring in this case.

Comment: @VivekMalhotra asking for tutorials is off-topic on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic please take better care before asking a question

Comment: http://www.zakariaamine.com/2016-02-09/testing-rest-api-spring, a blog post I wrote some time ago